# Receive/read BREAK condition on Linux serial port

Tags: linux, serial-port

I'd like to be able to detect a BREAK condition on a serial port in Linux. How is this done?

I'd like to detect when a BREAK condition starts *and* when it stops.

I hoped that if I did:

```
int serial_status;
ioctl(serial_fd, TIOCMGET, &serial_status);
```

then there would be a bit value showing a BREAK condition—but it seems there is no such thing.

I found [`tcsendbreak()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsendbreak) in `termios.h` for *sending* a break. I also found the [`tty_ioctl` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl) which describes how to send a break. But what about receiving a break?

**Note:** `BRKINT` has been suggested (which generates the signal `SIGINT` when a break occurs). But getting a `SIGINT` isn't such a useful API, for a few reasons:

- I can't tell what serial port it comes from, in a multiple-serial-port scenario.
- I can also get `SIGINT` from a user pressing Ctrl-C, when running the program at the terminal.
- If I'm running my program as a daemon, then the proviso "if the terminal is the controlling terminal of a foreground process group" wouldn't be true, would it?
- It's not possible to know how long the BREAK condition continues, and when it stops.

Comment: Look at `BRKINT` at that `termios` manpage you're linking to.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: I've added a note to my question, saying why I don't think `BRKINT` (generating `SIGINT`) is useful.

Comment: Review the source code of your USART/UART driver for the flag `TTY_BREAK`, which is a flag typically stuffed into the receive buffer when abnormal receive conditions (e.g. parity error, framing error, overrun or break) occur.  However the *line discipline* (the next stage of processing before userland gets the Rx data) will typically filter out the flags from the Rx data.  I vaguely recall one version of a *line discipline* that inserted 20 NULs for a break condition.  Or maybe 3 bytes of `0xff` and `0x00` and `0x00` -- http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/n_tty.c?v=2.6.36#L1002

Comment: @CraigMcQueen - did you every find out anything more about this problem? I am having a condition where i'm getting a long series of 0x00 bytes from a serial port which I think is indicating an error or break condition. I'm reading from the port in Canonical mode. I'm struggling with figuring out how to properly handle the case at runtime - should I close port? reopen port? flush port?. At this point i've tried setting the flat IGNBRK which doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Fra Only what I've written in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer I've been able to find so far is from the [`tcsendbreak()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsendbreak) description of `IGNBRK` and `BRKINT` constants for `c_iflag` in the `termios` structure. It says:

> When neither `IGNBRK` nor `BRKINT` are set, a BREAK reads as a null byte (`'\0'`), except when `PARMRK` is set, in which case it reads as the sequence `\377 \0 \0`.

(that is, `0xFF 0x00 0x00`)

So I guess I should probably set `PARMRK` and be prepared to do a little processing of the read bytes. This provides explicit information on parity/framing errors (although it's still not totally unambiguous whether `0xFF 0x00 0x00` represents a BREAK or some other parity/framing error).

Note however, I found [this patch for `PARMRK`](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1207.3/02184.html), which seems to imply there is a danger in older kernels that serial bytes could be dropped when `PARMRK` is being used.

It's also not clear if these bytes are sent continuously as long as the BREAK condition lasts, or if it's only sent once at the beginning of the BREAK condition. So it's not clear if the *end* of a BREAK condition can be detected via this method.

Comment: This is a little late, but in case someone comes along wondering the same thing...  It's also ambiguous to the receive hardware whether a break is a break, or a framing error.  The electrical semantics of a break are fairly simple:  The line is held low for an abnormally long time.  (How long?  IIRC, long enough to account for 2+ normal byte transfers at the given baud rate.  Could be mistaken.)  There's also no good way to know when a break starts because it's just a low line condition.  It's only a break if it's gone on long enough to qualify as a break vs. just being low.